# Making an upload video button in rails but still do not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a very simple rails program to upload video. And here is my code

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card blue-grey darken-1"> 
      <div class="card-image"> 
        <script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/<%= @course.video %>" async></script> 
        <script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
      </div>
```

My problem is, when I copy and paste the code from `wistia.com` to the box video, and try to upload it, the video still can not upload, I mean the video still does not change.

Could you please give me some ideas in this problem? I am a newbie and very confuse with this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you hosting the javascript assets yourself?  Do you have a link to the api documentation for the wistia javascripts use and installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load javascript from an external site you need to include the http protocol.  However without implementation instructions from your vendor, this probably won't do anything.  How does this javascript know where to insert video into your dom?  Look at the documentation here in their example https://wistia.com/support/embed-and-share/video-on-your-website

So in your html, load the javascript first then assign the div like this:

```
  <script src="http://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/j38ihh83m5.jsonp" async></script>
  <script src="http://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
  <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_j38ihh83m5" style="height:349px;width:620px">&nbsp;</div>
```

So if we assume your data object has a string with the id of the video, something like this should work:

```
<script src="http://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/<%= @course.video %>.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="http://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_<%= @course.video %>" style="height:349px;width:620px">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. You are right. By trying to code your comment, I could upload my video and changed it. Thank you very much.